# Retrieve substring between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this

```
  var str = "#it
              itA
              itB
              _
             #et
              etA
              etB
             _
             etC
             etD"
```

How can I retrieve elements between # and _. As of now I am splitting the text with new line but unable to workout this. Please help me on this. Please use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h728C/2/

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve?

Comment: note that your string object needs to be terminated with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've posted some solution in [fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/h728C/7/). It uses the Regex

```
var str = $('#a').text();
var pattern = /#([\s\S]*?)(?=_)/g;
var result = str.match(pattern);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i].length > 1) {
       result[i] = result[i].substring(1, result[i].length);
    }
    alert(result[i]);
}
```

Strip the end and beginning.

**Edit**

I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h728C/11/) and the code. Now it strips the beginning `#` and ending `_`. 
You can use either. Whichever is convenient.
​
​

Answer (score 9):

IF you simply want the FIRST string BETWEEN you can use:

```
var mys= str.substring(str.indexOf('#')+1,str.indexOf("_"));
```

this returns: "it itA itB"

Comment: But it does not return me all the patterns.. :-(

Comment: @SoI - yes and there was no indication of such in the question when this was posted.  Questions should clearly state the desire.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Next time I will take care :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why but this works:

```
var str = $('#a').text();
var results = [];
$.each(str.split("_"), function(){
    var a = this.toString().split("#");
    if(a.length===2) results.push(a[1]);
});

console.log(results);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of regex:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "").match(/#(.*?)_/g, "$1");
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h728C/16/).

Answer (score 1):

one line solution to get the array

```
var arrStr = str.split(/[#_]/);
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using regex here as it can be done more efficiently through other methods.

```js
function extractString(template, initChar, finalChar) {
  let i = 0;
  let data = [];
  do {
    if (template[i] == initChar) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < template.length; j++) {
        if (template[j] == finalChar) {
          data[data.length] = template.slice(i + 1, j);
          i = j + 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  while (++i < template.length);
  console.log(data)
  return data;
}

extractString("#adj#, #brown# fox jumps over the lazy #dog#.","#","#");
```