# Customized splitting of a string

Tags: javascript

From this post [Retrieve substring between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313071/retrieve-substring-between-two-characters/9313263#comment11749069_9313263) I am able to retrieve strings between two characters easily. But I want to extend this like below. If I have a string like below

```
 var str = "#a
            b
            c
            _
            ele1
            ele2
            #d
            e
            f
            _
            ele3
            ";
```

from the above string I want to retrieve an array like below

```
     arr = [ "#a
               b
               c
              _",
             "ele1",
             "ele2",
             "#d
               e
               f
              _",
             "ele3"
           ]
```

Thanks. Please help me on this. Please use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JLwbf/) fiddle.

Comment: So basically we are going to do your homeworks throughout all your questions ?

Comment: @Didier Ghys I did my homework But I want make it perfect with the help of forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is what split() is for.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

EDIT: If you do not want to lose delims, try this approach

1) Use the replace method to replace all instances of your delim with another symbol. 
   Meaning, if you had "/" as your delim, replace it with "/%"
2) and then call split on this new delim.

Comment: Not exactly.  `split` eliminates the separator from the result.  The posted example maintains it.